# How to fix group in complex query in rails or do a join on two separate query results and then query again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have been stuck with this problem for a while at work. The data given has been radically changed as I just need the general idea of how to approach the problem, and it would not be possible to provide the actual schema of the tables.

I have a table `Users` and and another table `Membership`. And each user has a one to many relationship with membership through the `user_membership` table. A mock up of the following table is shown below:

| id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | john@gmail.com |
| 2 | James | james@gmail.com |
| ... | ... | ... |

| id | user_id | membership_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 1 | 5 |
| ... | ... | ... |

| id | created_at |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 31st Dec 2021 |
| 2 | 1st Jan 2022 |
| 3 | 2nd Jan 2022 |
| 4 | 3rd Jan 2022 |
| 5 | 4th Jan 2022 |
| ... | ... |

I have some level of rather complex querying that returns an `ActiverecordRelation`.
ie:
`users = Users.select(....)`

I then need to chain the above query with another query that allows each `user` with their latest `membership_created_at` date. Ie:
<User, id: 1, name: John ,email: john@gmail.com, latest_membership_created_at: 4th Jan 2022>
<User, id: 2, name: James ,email: james@gmail.com, latest_membership_created_at: 31st Dec 2021>

My approach:

```
users = users.joins(user_memberships: :membership).merge(User.all).group(:id).select('membership.*, MAX(membership.created_at) AS membership_created_at_raw')
```

I get an error:

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function...
```

**Qn 1: Is there anyway I can fix this?**

In another related note, is it also possible to do a join of the result of 2 queries? I am thinking perhaps I can do a group of `user_membership` table by `user_id` and join with the `membership` table. Something like

```
users_created_at = User.all.joins(user_memberships: :membership[).group(:id).select('user.id, MAX(memberships.created_at) AS membership_created_at_raw')
```

**Qn 2: Can we then somehow do an innerjoin between `users` and `users_created_at` using rails?**

Thank you!

Comment: can you show your full query?

Comment: Why this part? `select('membership.*, MAX(membership.created_at) AS membership_created_at_raw')` this seems illogical since it will return all memberships. Did you actually mean `select('users.*, MAX(membership.created_at) AS membership_created_at_raw')` because that will work fine and return the user records with a virtual attribute called `membership_created_at_raw` (which you could change the alias to `latest_membership_created_at` and you will have your desired out put?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```rb
User.select(
  'DISTINCT ON (users.id) users.id, memberships.*'
).joins(
  user_memberships: :membership
).order('users.id, memberships.created_at DESC')
```

Or raw SQL query

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (users.id) users.id, memberships.*
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_memberships ON user_memberships.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN memberships ON memberships.id = user_memberships.membership_id
ORDER BY users.id, memberships.created_at DESC
```